# Laravel - pass 2 variables from view to controller with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have this function for my delete button

```
<a href="#" onclick='deleteFile("{{ ($event->id) }}", "{{ ($file->name) }}")' class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">L&ouml;schen</a>
```

and the route in routes/web.php

```
Route::post('/delete-file', 'MyController@deleteEventFile');
```

that hits this function

```
public function deleteEventFile($eventid, $filename){
   dd($eventid);
}
```

and this is my ajax function:

```
function deleteFile(eventid, filename){
    //alert(filename);
    //alert(eventid);
    $.ajax({
      url: '/delete-file/',
      type: "post",
      data:{ _token: "{{csrf_token()}}", eventid: eventid, filename: filename },
      dataType: 'json',
    });
}
```

And i always get this error:

```
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\MyController::deleteEventFile()
```

my variables can't get through...
How to pass the eventid and filename to controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, you are expecting route to give 2 params - `eventid` & `filename` into the controller method.

Instead it you should code your method like this:

```
public function deleteEventFile() {
   $event_id = request()->get('eventid');
   $file_name = request()->get('filename');
}
```

> Fetch the POST data from the laravel's `request()` method instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: well you got it! but how does this request() knows what are the variables?

Comment: @lewis4u - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: yes i will but there is a time limit 8 min..now it's 3 min and counting. That means you can't accept an answer for 8 min after you post a question. Actually maybe it's 10 min...because when i tried it was 8

Answer (score 0):

You can access your parameters in controller using Request like bellow.

```
public function deleteEventFile(Request $request){
   dd($request->eventid);
}
```